# Jquery json : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am retrieving data via JSON but the problem is that I am getting error as such "Cannot read property 'productid' of undefined".

JSON File (data.json)

```
{
    "Products": [
        {
            "productid": "135",
            "productname": "Shirt",
            "productqty": "3",
            "seller_3": "150.00",
            "seller_2": "151.00",
            "seller_7": "153.00",
            "seller_6": "159.00",
            "seller_5": "155.00",
            "seller_1": "157.00",
            "seller_4": "152.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

The execution code is

```
var itemQty = 134;
$.getJSON( "../data.json", function(data) {
    if (data.Products.length == 0) {
        /*do nothing*/
    } else if(data.Products.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.Products[i].productid); // ITS RETURN THE VALUE 135
            if (data.Products[i].productid == itemID) { // <--- ERROR THIS LINE
                if (data.Products[i].productqty == itemQty) {
                    newQuantity = eval(data.Products[i].productqty);
                } else {
                    var newQuantity = eval(itemQty);
                }
                if (newQuantity > options.quantityLimit) {
                    newQuantity = options.quantityLimit
                }
                data.Products[i].productqty = newQuantity;
            } else {
                data.Products.push(cartItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the console.log, it returns the value which is 135, where as when comparing in the IF statement, I am getting the error Cannot read property 'productid' of undefined.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Why the `eval`'s when you could just use `parseInt`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are modifying the list of Products from inside the loop. So take a closer look at whatever is setting the value for `cartItem`.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
    ...
    data.Products.push(cartItem);
  }
```

It is a bad idea to add new items to a list while you're iterating over it. You are likely to have an infinite loop depending on how `itemID` and `cartItem` are set.
Try reading the `.length` value one time before starting the loop, so new items won't be iterated:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.Products.length; i < len; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Noted. I modified the script. Thank you very much.